# String match algorithms in R

Tags: r, string, algorithm, match

I would like to find the string match, with number of characters which are matching from the start. I have two strings `a <- "ABCDBADCABC"`, `b <- "ABC"`. I want to find the match of `b` in `a`. I am interested to find if `b <- "ABC"` exists at the start of `a <- "ABCDBADCABC"`. I am not looking for other locations of string match other than start.

**Other example:** `b <- ABCDBADCABC`, `a <- "ABCDAB"`, here only four characters of `a` match with `b` from the start. So output will be `ABCD` match from `a`.
What are the available options in `R` to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would keep it simple and make `a` and `b` vectors contain individual characters. Then string matching is straight forward.

```
## Make a and b
b = "ABCDBADCABC"
a = "ABCDAB"
```

Find the length of the shortest vector

```
min_char = min(nchar(a), nchar(b))
```

Then split `a` and `b` up

```
a_split =  strsplit(substr(a,1, min_char), "")[[1]]
b_split =  strsplit(substr(b,1, min_char), "")[[1]]
```

Compare using standard operators

```
comp = a_split == b_split
```

Find the first occurrence of `FALSE`

```
which.min(comp) - 1
```

---

With less code:

```
compare(a, b)
```

where

```
compare = function(a, b) {
  min_char = min(nchar(a), nchar(b))
  a_split =  strsplit(substr(a,1, min_char), "")[[1]]
  b_split =  strsplit(substr(b,1, min_char), "")[[1]]
  comp = a_split == b_split
  which.min(comp) - 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Isn't there anything with less code.

Comment: If you want less code, you could try your luck posting this at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/. SO is not meant for shorter code contests.